# Postgresql problem storing big int in jsonb

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have jsonb object that has key/value hwid:99884131175086353 in Postgresql. Value is 17 character integer. When i query this object with psycopg2 deriver using python3 i get hwid:99884131175086352 . Any idea?

In db querying it using pgAdmin it is

```
{

    "hwid": 99884131175086353,

}
```

When i query it from python3 code it is

```
{

    "hwid": 99884131175086352,

}
```

Comment: There is no way to guess what you're doing wrong, not seeing what you're doing.

Comment: You can only reliably work with integers in the range `[-(2**53)+1, (2**53)-1]` in JSON and `99884131175086353 > 9007199254740991` so you could be running into a precision issue somewhere when switching between integer and floating point values inside someone's JSON implementation. If you're not doing arithmetic on that `hwid` then it is really a "string that happens to contain only digits" so store it as a string.